# Quartale benennen

Tags: single-word-request, time

Gibt es im Deutschen systematische und allgemein verständliche Namen für die vier kalendarischen Quartale?

1. Quartal (Q1): Januar + Februar + März ≈ KW01–13
2. Quartal (Q2): April + Mai + Juni ≈ KW14–26
3. Quartal (Q3): Juli + August + September ≈ KW27–39
4. Quartal (Q4): Oktober + November + Dezember ≈ KW40–52/53

Der leider etwas unbefriedigende [Wikipedia-Artikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartal) verweist auf die historische Festlegung der katholischen *Quatember* oder *Fronfasten* und die darauf beruhenden ehemals üblichen [Bergquartale](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bergquartal):

1. ***R**eminiscere*
2. ***T**rinitatis*
3. ***C**rucis*
4. ***L**uciae*

### Hintergrund

Das Kalenderjahr, das Gartenjahr, das Wirtschafts- oder Geschäftsjahr u.v.a. werden häufig in vier etwa gleich lange Abschnitte eingeteilt.  Diese werden je nach Jargon und Zweck *Jahreszeit, Saison/Season, Trimester, Vierteljahr* oder *Quartal* genannt. Die Länge beträgt meist 3 Monate, 13 Wochen oder 91 Tage (mit Abweichungen durch die Struktur des Kalenders oder signifikante Fixdaten). Das [liturgische Kirchenjahr](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchenjahr) ist mit seinen *(Fest-)Kreisen* sehr unregelmäßig.
Wann die jeweiligen Abschnitte beginnen und welcher als der erste angesehen wird, variiert. In früheren Zeiten wurde bspw. der Frühlingsanfang am 1. März, zur Tag-und-Nacht-Gleiche oder zu Ostern als Jahresbeginn angesehen.

Für *Frühling/Frühjahr, Sommer, Herbst, Winter* gibt es bspw. verschiedene Definitionen als Jahreszeit oder Saison (auf der Nordhalbkugel).

- **meteorologisch** (Mitteleuropa):

  1. März – Mai,
  2. Juni – August,
  3. September – November,
  4. Dezember – Februar;

  vgl. traditionelle englische Trimester:

  1. *Epiphany term* (06.01.), *Hilary term* (14.01.)
  2. *Lent term* (die Fastenzeit liegt überwiegend im März), *Easter term* (Ostern ist meist im April)
  3. *Trinity term* (Trinitatis ist meist im Juni), *Summer term* (21.06.)
  4. *Michaelmas term* (29.09.) – üblicherweise 1. Trimester des akademischen Jahres
- **astronomisch** / **kultisch**:

  1. rund um März-Tagnachtgleiche, nach Imbolg/Lichtmess
  2. rund um Juni-Sonnenwende, nach Walpurgisnacht/Beltane
  3. rund um September-Tagnachtgleiche, nach Lughnasadh/Lammas
  4. rund um Dezember-Sonnenwende, nach Halloween/Samhain/Allerheiligen
- **astrologisch**:

  1. ab März-Tagnachtgleiche (Widder, Stier, Zwillinge),
  2. ab Juni-Sonnenwende (Krebs, Löwe, Jungfrau),
  3. ab September-Tagnachtgleiche (Waage, Skorpion, Schütze),
  4. ab Dezember-Sonnenwende (Steinbock, Wassermann, Fische)
- **akademisch** ([Trimester](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimester_(Studium)), selten und uneinheitlich), bspw.:

  1. Oktober – Dezember,
  2. Januar – März,
  3. April – Juni,
  4. Juli – September.
- **modisch** (Kollektion, ungefähr 1 Monat vor meteorolgischer Jahreszeit, früher an WSV und SSV festzumachen):

  1. Februar – April,
  2. Mai – Juli,
  3. August – Oktober,
  4. November – Januar
- **hedonistisch**(?), Urlaub, Gastgewerbe (lokal sehr unterschiedlich, z.B. *Skisaison* vs. *Freibadsaison*):

  1. *Vorsaison*,
  2. *Hauptsaison*,
  3. *Nachsaison*,
  4. *Nebensaison*

Im Einzelhandel gibt es verschiedene *Saisons* oder *Zeiten*, die sich nach den lokal verfügbaren Nahrungsmitteln (d.h. **gastronomisch**) oder wichtigen Festen richten und sich durch entsprechende jährlich wiederkehrende Angebote und Dekorationen auszeichnen, aber m.W. existiert kein einheitliches Schema.
Beispiele:

- *Spargelsaison/-zeit* (bis 24. Juni),
- *Oktoberfestzeit* (eher September),
- *Kürbiszeit / Halloween* (vor 1. November),
- *Grünkohlsaison*,
- *Vorweihnachtssaison* (*Herbstgebäck* ab 1. September, Schokonikoläuse später),
- *Weihnachtssaison / Weihnachtsmarktzeit / Advent* (bis 24. Dezember, in manchen Branchen *Hauptsaison*),
- *Karneval* (vor Fastnacht/Aschermittwoch),
- *Fasten- / Osterzeit*.

Die Saisons bzw. Hin- und Rückrunden der verschiedenen nationalen und internationalen Sportligen dauern meist länger; Welt- und Europameisterschaften liegen üblicherweise in der sonst spielfreien Zeit.
In Hochschulen des deutschen Sprachraums sind eher Semester (also Halbjahre) als Trimester üblich und meist beginnt das akademische Jahr im September oder Oktober des Vorjahres. Auch viele Berichts- und Haushaltsjahre beginnen nicht am 1. Januar.

Comment: Suchst Du nach "Namen" im Sinne von Frühling, Herbst und Winter? Reichen Dir Q1, Q2, Q3 und Q4 nicht?

Comment: @Raketenolli Durchnummerieren ist wohl die üblichste Lösung, wenn die Jahreszeiten nicht zutreffen oder zu ungenau wären. Komposita wären völlig okay, bspw. liest man gelegentlich _Weihnachtsquartal_ oder _Osterquartal_, aber deren Zeiträume sind nicht ganz eindeutig und es fehlen noch zwei analoge dazu.

Comment: Das ist viel Text für eine simple Frage.

Comment: @Em1 Ja, ich wollte deutlich machen, warum die Jahreszeiten eben nicht das sind, was ich suche (und trotzdem meint offenbar jemand, dass es eine General Reference täte). Ich habe die eigentliche Frage jetzt an den Anfang verschoben.

Comment: Das Finanzamt (für Viele die höchste weltliche Instanz...) bricht die Quartale an den Monaten (1-3, 4-6, 7-9, 10-12, irrelevant vieviele Tage der Monat tatsächlich hat) und nennt sie einfach 1-4. Ich denke, das ist die praktikabelste Teilung.

Comment: Ja, ich bin der Meinung, dass es eine General Reference täte. Bei z. B. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartal würde ich dann "allgemein verständliche Namen" erwarten und finde I...IV bzw. Q1...Q4. So wie ich unter Jahreszeit eine entsprechende Auflistung finde.

Comment: soweit ich weiss, sind die 4 astronomischen Jahreszeiten kalendarisch fest definiert zwischen Tag-und-Nachgleiche und Sonnenwende. Die metereologischen Jahreszeiten sind Länder/Geographie-spezifisch, und wurden meiner Erinnerung nach erst in den letzten 10-15 Jahren im Wetterbericht populär (wohl da man her krumme Zahlen vermeidet, und das Wetter direkt vom Publikum erleb-bar ist). https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jahreszeit

Answer (score 11):

Wir nennen sie in der Regel "erstes, zweites, drittes, viertes Quartal". Das reicht vollkommen - und ist selbsterklärend. Bei "KWs" muss man dann schon wieder rechnen - oder nach dem Kalender gehen, um sicher zu sein, dass man die gleiche meint. Was anderes kenne ich nicht - im allgemeinen deutschen Sprachgebrauch.

Comment: Kalenderwochen passen sowieso nicht, weil sie nichts mit der Monatsaufteilung des Jahres zu tun haben. Z.B. KW 01/2021 : 04.01.2021 - 10.01.2021 und KW 53 /2020 : 28.12.2020 - 03.01.2021. Man beachte, dass es **immer** genau 53 KW gibt, die Tage eines Jahres enthalten, weil 52 x 7 = 364. Allerdings kann eine dieser KW zum Vorjahr gehören (vgl. obiges Beispiel). Manche Jahre haben also 52 KW (wie 2021), andere 53 KW (we 2020).

Comment: Es gibt sogar Jahre, deren Tage in 54 Kalenderwochen fallen: Schaltjahre, die an einem Sonntag beginnen und an einem Montag enden (zuletzt 2012). KWs sind aber nach DIN EN ISO 8601-1 genau einem Jahr vollständig zugeordnet, daher hat so ein _Wochenjahr_ normalerweise vier Quartale mit genau 13 Wochen und manchmal eine zusätzliche 14. im letzten (zuletzt 2020).

Answer (score 5):

Ich habe mir mal die [Fundstellen für `*quartal`](http://www.dwds.de/?view=1&qu=*quartal) in den beim DWDS öffentlich verfügbaren Korpora angeguckt, wobei die meisten aus der *Zeit* der letzten 5 Jahre stammen.

Für das erste und letzte Quartal eines Buchhaltungsjahres oder Kalenderjahres sind auch *Startquartal*, *Auftaktquartal* und *Schlussquartal* (seltener: *Abschlussquartal*) sowie *Weihnachtsquartal* gebräuchlich. Es gibt Fundstellen für *Rumpfquartal*, dessen genaue Bedeutung mir aber vorerst verschlossen bleibt. Für das zweite und dritte Quartal scheint es keine ähnlichen Bezeichnungen zu geben.

Besonders häufige Komposita sind die relativen Zeitangaben *Vorjahresquartal* (gleicher Zeitraum vor einem Jahr), *Vorquartal*, *Folgequartal* und *Vergleichsquartal*. Gelegentlich wird vor allem nach den Ordinalattributen *erstes, zweites, drittes, viertes / letztes* zwischen *Kalenderquartal* und *Geschäftsquartal* unterschieden, letzteres wird häufig im Kontext (z.B. in Klammern) näher spezifiziert, wohingegen *Jahresquartal* heute eher nicht mehr verwendet wird.

1. ***erstes Kalenderquartal*** / *Jahresquartal* / *Vierteljahr*
2. ***zweites Kalenderquartal*** / *Jahresquartal* / *Vierteljahr*
3. ***drittes Kalenderquartal*** / *Jahresquartal* / *Vierteljahr*
4. ***viertes / letztes Kalenderquartal*** / *Jahresquartal* / *Vierteljahr*

Beispielsweise im Kontext der Krankenversicherung ist auch vom *Abrechnungsquartal* die Rede, sonst je nach Branche auch *Unternehmensquartal*, *Produktionsquartal*, *Vertriebsquartal*, *Steuerquartal*, *Berichtsquartal*, *Finanzquartal* oder *Haushaltsquartal* sowie je nach Bilanz auch qualitativ *Verlustquartal, Wachstumsquartal, Gewinnquartal, Katastrophenquartal, Erfolgsquartal, Boomquartal, Rekordquartal*.

Die Verwendung der Jahreszeiten in Komposita mit *-quartal* ist einigemaßen intuitiv verständlich, aber nicht (mehr) besonders üblich. Für globale Statistiken sind sie ungeeignet, aber da der deutsche Sprachraum fast ausschließlich auf der Nordhalbkugel liegt, sind sie immerhin weitgehend eindeutig. Allerdings werden sie scheinbar, wie auch *Weihnachtsquartal*, in der Finanzpresse auch verwendet, um ein Geschäftsquartal kalendarisch einzuordnen, ohne dass es genau dem jeweiligen Dreimonatszeitraum genau entsprechen müsste.

1. ***Winterquartal***
2. ***Frühlingsquartal / Frühjahrsquartal***
3. ***Sommerquartal***
4. ***Herbstquartal***

(Im *Zeit*-Korpus gibt es eine Fundsstelle für *Frühsommerquartal* – keine Ahnung, welcher genaue Zeitraum damit gemeint ist.)

Die liturgischen bzw. bergmännischen Quartale sind heute weitgehend unbekannt und damit unbrauchbar.

1. *Reminiscere (R)*
2. *Trinitatis (T)*
3. *Crucis (C)*
4. *Luciae (L)*